# how to pass nullable field value as parameter to a function that takes none nullable parameters?

Tags: c#

I have got a field that is declared to accept nullable value. I am passing this field data to a method that takes no nullable parameters to preform some calculation and return the result. How Can I pass a a field value that its declared to take nullable variables to a method that expects none nullable variables.

Code

```
public static decimal CalculatePercentage(decimal price, decimal updatePrice, bool updateType)
{
    var precentage = (price / 100) * updatePrice;
    if (updateType)
        return  price += precentage;
    else
        return price -= precentage;
}
```

// Passing the value of the model price ex 46.

```
   CalculatePercentage(model.price, updatePrice, updateType);
```

model

```
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: modal.price.Value

Comment: Either using an explicit cast `(decimal) model.Price` or using the `Value` property `model.Price.Value`. Although you will get an exception either way if the property is null.

Comment: Or pass a default value if null: `model.Price.GetValueOrDefault(0m)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast your value to the accepted one like this:

```
CalculatePercentage((decimal)model.price, updatePrice, updateType);
```

if it is null will throw error though

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .Value property of the nullable type

```
CalculatePercentage(model.Price?.Value, updatePrice, updateType);
```

assuming it has a value,

you can check its existence with the `HasValue` boolean property